# pass through 2 Basic Authentication levels for the same URL using request module

Tags: node.js, request, basic-authentication

I have a web service that uses request module nodejs to get into another service in php protected by basic authentication, using below code, everything was working as expected

```
request.get(url).auth(cred.username, cred.password, false);
```

we recently implemented another level of basic authentication on the web server level for different purposes, now I have 2 levels of authentication, I tried to duplicate this request command by doing

```
request.get(url).auth(cred.username01, cred.password01, false);
request.get(url).auth(cred.username02, cred.password02, false);
```

this did not work, anyone had similar issue before, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is Asynchronous, you will need to execute the second get request inside of a callback for the first one.

Comment: Hello Robert, Thanks, Actually am doing this on purpose, am running the code synchronously inside a fiber, even though, not sure how this is gonna help if it was a asynchronous because I already tried this, would you please clarify.